# Errors reduce at each step of Fixed-point iteration

Tags: fixed-point-theorems

We have known that if $g: [a,b] \rightarrow [a,b]$, $g$ is differential in $(a,b)$, $k \in (0,1)$ and $|g'(x)| \leq k, \forall x \in (a,b)$ then $g$ has a unique fixed point $x^*$.
Moreover, for all $x_0\in [a,b]$, $x_{n+1}:=g(x_n) ,\forall n$ , we have $x_n \in [a,b], \forall n $ and $x_n$ converges to  $x^*$.

Let see a problem, use the Fixed-point interation to find an approximation to correct to within $10^{-t}$ for $f(x)=0 \Leftrightarrow x=g(x)$.

We have to choose $x_0 \in [a,b]$ and let $x_{n+1}:=g(x_n),\forall n$.
But for each step $x_n \in \mathbb {R} $/$ {\mathbb{Q}}$ , we just can take finite number of digits,  we round $x_n$ off to $l$ decimal places ($l>k$)   $$u_n:=\overline{x}_n=x_n+r_n , |r_n|\leq \frac{1}{2}10^{-l}$$
Then $u_{n+1}:=\overline{g(u_n)}=g(u_n)+r_{n+1}$

So we have $u_0=x_0+r_0$ and $ u_{n+1}=g(u_n)+r_{n+1}, \forall n$.

I want to prove: exits $n_0$ such that $$|u_{n+1}-x^*|\leq \frac{1}{2}10^{-t}, \forall n \geq n_0.$$

My ideal is:

If I can prove for $l$ is choosen, $u_n \in [a,b], \forall n$ **(1)**

then I have

$$u_1=g(u_0)+r_1=g(x_0+r_0)+r_1=g(x_0)+g'(c_0)r_0+r_1 = x_1++g'(c_0)r_0+r_1$$
($c_0$ is between $x_0+r_0$ and $x_0$).

...
$$u_{n+1}=x_{n+1}+g'(c_0)...g'(c_{n})r_0+...+g'(c_n)r_n+r_{n+1}$$
So
 $$|u_{n+1}-x^*|\leq |x_{n+1}-x^*|+\sum_{i=0}^n{|r_{i }|k^{n+1-i}}\leq|x_{n+1}-x^*|+\frac{1}{2}10^{-l}\frac{1-k^{n+2}}{1-k}$$

As $x_n \rightarrow x^*$, $\epsilon:= \frac{1}{2}10^{-t}-\frac{1}{2}10^{-l}\frac{1}{1-k}>0$ (choose $k >l$ and $ 10^{l-k} > \frac{1}{1-k}$), exits $n_0$ such that for all $n \geq n_0$ $|x_{n+1}-x^*|<\epsilon$

Then $|u_{n+1}-x^*|\leq \frac{1}{2}10^{-t}, \forall n \geq n_0.$

Is it ok? I still can't prove **(1)**, help me, thanks!

Comment: What is your fixed point mapping? Is it just $x \mapsto 0$? In general the argument to show that a fixed point mapping $g$ maps $[a,b]$ into itself is case-specific, except in certain extremely special cases (e.g. $g$ is globally contractive).

Comment: I also don't really know what this truncation thing has to do with anything. You can deal with finite precision arithmetic after you've dealt with the problem in infinite precision arithmetic.

Comment: Oh I was wrong, when find solution of $f(x)=0 \Leftrightarrow x=g(x)$ so $x$ is fixed point of $g$